# split data matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a data matrix with 100,000 rows of values corresponding to methylation values across several cell types. I would like to visually display the changes in methylation in a clustered heatmap. To get the data into a more manageable size I was thinking of creating a new data matrix every 10th or so row. Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you just clarify whether you want a new matrix containing only every 10th row from the initial matrix, or separate matrices for each chunk of 10 rows?

Comment: @GavinSimpson: Thanks for your response - I was looking for the a single new matrix with only every 10th row from the original matrix. I was able to do this using your answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `seq` and combinations of arguments. E.g.:

```
m1 <- matrix(runif(100000*10), ncol = 10)

m2 <- m1[seq(from = 1, to = nrow(m1), by = 10), ]

> dim(m2)
[1] 10000    10
```

How does this work? Look at what this does:

```
> sq <- seq(from = 1, to = nrow(m1), by = 10)
> head(sq)
[1]  1 11 21 31 41 51
> tail(sq)
[1] 99941 99951 99961 99971 99981 99991
> nrow(m1)
[1] 100000
```

We specify to go from the first row to the last incrementing 10 each step. This gives us rows 1, 11, 21, etc. When we get to the end of the sequence, even though we specified `nrow(m1)` (which is 100000) the last element in our sequence in 99991. This is because 99991 + 10 would take us beyond the `from` argument limit (beyond 100000) and hence that is not included in the sequence.

Comment: Perhaps I am understanding the question wrong. Isn't the OP asking to split the matrix into contiguous chunks of rows. IIUC your code is only picking every 10th row.

Comment: @asb Indeed and I have asked for clarification. My gut instinct is that breaking a 100,000 row matrix in 10,000 10-row matrices is *not* what the OP wants unless they plan to look at all 10,000 heatmaps, but I am frequently baffled by what people attempt to do with R and large data sets so I will remain confused until the OP enlightens us.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following which takes your large matrix `m` and generates a list of smaller matrices. It generates a sequence of indices that breaks at every `chunk.length` values and then collects the chunks.

```
list.of.matrices <- lapply(X=seq.int(1, nrow(m), by=chunk.length)),
                           FUN=function (k) {
                             m[k + seq_len(chunk.length) - 1, ])
                           })
```

However, if you have 100,000 rows, it will be wasteful for your RAM to save all these chunks separately. Perhaps, you can just do the required computation on the subsets and save only the results. Just a suggestion.